# closeEvent and QMessageBox seems to block updating UI

Tags: python, pyside, qmessagebox

I have been getting this issue for hours now. I have investigated a lot of things (I even created a custom QDialog), but now I am determined that it's the closeEvent and QMessageBox combination that causes this problem. What I want to know is if there is any way for me to overcome this problem?

**Issue**:

I want to allow my code to clean up all its used resources such as threads, DLLs, etc prior to closing. It takes a few seconds to actually do the whole clean up. In order to *assure* the user that the application is functioning properly, I want to 'print-out' a status message confirming that the application is trying to clean-up its resources.

However, using the codes below all I could get is "Are you sure.....". The "Stopping App....." message is not inserted into `processEdit`.

My code snippet, test.py:

```
import sys, os, time
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *
from time import sleep

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(350, 100, 300, 300)
        self.processEdit = QTextEdit()
        self.grid = QGridLayout()
        self.grid.addWidget(self.processEdit, 0, 0)
        self.setLayout(self.grid)
        self.show()

    def closeEvent(self, event = False):
        self.processEdit.insertHtml("\n\n Are you sure.....")
        if isinstance(event, QCloseEvent):
            event.ignore()
        confirm = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message', "Are you sure you want to quit?", QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)
        if confirm == QMessageBox.Yes:
            self.processEdit.insertHtml("\n\n Stopping App.....")

            # clean up resources and status reports here.
            time.sleep(5) # only here for the snippet

            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    qapp = QApplication(sys.argv)
    c = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(qapp.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text is correctly inserted. However, the problem is that you block the event loop by performing sleep/cleanup *inside* the closeEvent callback. Since the UI updating utilizes the event system the next paint event is not processed before closing the application.

In PyQt (don't have PySide) I was able to work around this issue with

```
self.processEdit.insertHtml("\n\n Stopping App.....")

event.accept()

self.repaint()
qapp.processEvents()

# clean up resources and status reports here.
time.sleep(5) # only here for the snippet
```

But I think this is bad practice (not only because of accessing a global variable). You should attempt to keep your GUI responsive, even during shutdown. See [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Keeping_the_GUI_Responsive).

Comment: The repaint is redundant, and the application instance can be accessed with `QtGui.qApp`. I agree it's not a good idea to leave the GUI unresponsive during shutdown - perhaps it's better to hide the window and/or show a splashscreen.

Comment: Great. I didn't know about `repaint()` function. I did actually plan to ensure that the GUI is always responsive. the sleep is just a.. hmm.. something to do.. on the snippet. haha 

Thanks again.

Comment: @kazemakase I have already accepted your answer, but i am wondering if you could follow up on what you said; "block the event loop by performing sleep/cleanup inside the closeEvent callback". Is there any other place to perform clean up prior to the termination of the application? (should have ask this earlier, but i was overcome with joy that it worked). (hmm.. should i ask this on another question o_O)

Comment: While the program is inside an event handler no other events can be processed. Inserting the the call to qapp.processEvents() is actually a hack that ensures that the repaint event gets processed. What happens is that one round of event processing is started while the closing event is still being processed.

You could try to split the calls to sys.exit() and qapp.exec_(). qapp.exec_() blocks until the program finishes. Afterwards you can do your cleanup. This way the GUI is already closed when your cleanup code is executed.